# Pass both Form and Data Grid View as parameters

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a `Sub` which takes both `Form` and `DataGripView` as parameters.

```
Public Sub ExecuteReaderDataGridView(SQLQuery As String,
                                     TargetDataGridView As DataGridView,
                                     TargetForm As Form)
```

Up to now, I use both parameters but now there is a need to use one of the two depends on the case.

Is there a way to avoid create two `Subs` one with `DataGridView` as a parameter and one with `Form`?

Comment: Just add a 3rd parameter which indicates what to use in the Sub. But I would still create two additional methods that then handle the specific use case and are called from your initial method. The goal should always be to keep methods as specific and short as possible.

Comment: In your Sub you could check if `TargetDataGridView` or `TargetForm` is Nothing and run the appropriate code for the situation.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville how i will pass nothing to parameter? When i call sub?

Comment: `ExecuteReaderDataGridView(SQLQuery, Nothing, TargetForm)` / `ExecuteReaderDataGridView(SQLQuery, TargetDataGridView, Nothing)`

Comment: The issue is really in your first statement "I have a Sub which takes both Form and DataGripView as parameters.", you should not mix your UI and your business logic. Your `ExecuteReaderDataGridView` could raise an event which your UI handles and puts in the appropriate place. I'm guessing your reader executes on the UI thread too...

Comment: You are writing spaghetti code.  That should probably just be a function that returns data, without passing any UI components.  The `SQLQuery` variable strongly hints that you aren't using SQL Parameters either.

Comment: *"how i will pass nothing to parameter"*. By literally passing `Nothing` to that parameter when you call the method. You know how to pass a value. Why would passing `nothing` be any more difficult?

Comment: Reading your comments, I decided to create two separated functions. That's for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize function overloading:

```
' Sub that takes the query and a DGV:
Public Sub ExecuteReaderDataGridView(SQLQuery As String, TargetDataGridView As DataGridView)

    ExecuteReaderDataGridView(SQLQuery, TargetDataGridView, Nothing)

End Sub

' Sub that takes the query and a Form:
Public Sub ExecuteReaderDataGridView(SQLQuery As String, TargetForm As Form)

    ExecuteReaderDataGridView(SQLQuery, Nothing, TargetForm)

End Sub

' Your original Sub:
Public Sub ExecuteReaderDataGridView(SQLQuery As String, TargetDataGridView As DataGridView,TargetForm As Form)

' You'll need to modify your original Sub by adding code
' to determine if TargetDataGridView or TargetForm is Nothing.

End Sub
```

Comment: This a correct way to do it however, OP: "Is there a way to avoid create two Subs one with DataGridView as a parameter and one with Form?"

Comment: I understood the OP's "avoid creating two Subs" as two subs with content, not just a call to the final function overload.